# Service Discovery for the device

Tags: java, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, netbeans-8

I am working on Raspberry pi and trying to connect dell pc with raspberry pi using bluetooth.My class is implementing DiscoveryListener that overrides four methods:deviceDiscovered,inquiryCompleted,servicesDiscovered and servicesearchCompleted.
But serviceDiscovered method is not executed only..this is my code for serviceDiscovered:

```java
@Override
public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord)
{
    System.out.println("hiii");
    for (int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++)
    {
        String url =
                servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
        if (url == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        DataElement serviceName = servRecord[i].getAttributeValue(0x0100);
        if (serviceName != null)
        {
            System.out.println("service " + serviceName.getValue() + " found " + url);

            if (serviceName.getValue().equals("OBEX Object Push"))
            {
                sendMessageToDevice(url);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("service found " + url);
        }
    }
}
```

Can i know the reason behind this?
Thanks

Comment: If you're sure that `servicesDiscovered()` isn't executed you should focus on the code which is calling this method, not the method itself.

Comment: Call to the method is appropriate..but i read somewhere that if these       methods do not return anything then there is possibility that system have blocked all the services..whether this could be the reason ??

Comment: do you see `"hiii"` in the standard output?

Comment: no..flow is not going inside this method only..so hi is not displayed..

Comment: you say _flow is not going inside this method_ . So, see my first comment. It seems the code of `servicesDiscovered()` is not responsible for your problem

Comment: May be.i dont know..method is called in this way:         DiscoveryAgent agent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();                       agent.searchServices( attrIDs,uuidSet,device,listener);                              i dont see anything wrong in this too.

Comment: what happens during debugging?

Comment: Listening on 57031
User program running
LineBreakpoint MyDiscoveryListener.java : 84 successfully submitted.
Breakpoint hit at line 84 in class helloworld.MyDiscoveryListener by thread main.
Thread main stopped at MyDiscoveryListener.java:84.

Comment: you don't make it easy to help you... I don't see a relation between your last comment and your code. I don't follow this question anymore, sorry. Take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)